# Add version query tag to all images

Tags: plugin-development, thumbnails

I want caching all images on my site and prevent the browser download the images all times, so I would like add an version query tag to all images (for example: 
`?v=20160505`)

How can I add this for image urls?
Now I use this code to show images in my theme:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail->ID, 'thumbnail' );
```

Comment: May I ask why? A image is not dinamic by definition.

Comment: @cybmeta, extremely rare but might happen (delete image, upload another under the same name. IIRC edit image can also cause that)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know why you want to do it when there's [`update_post_thumbnail_cache()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_thumbnail_cache/) in WordPress and [set expire headers](https://www.google.com/#q=set+expires+header+for+images) on server side. But you can try this in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_src', function($img, $id, $size, $icon) {
  
    $img[0] = $img[0] . '?v={$some_version}';

    return $img;
    
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 4);
```

Comment: +1 but probably better to use file modification time than hardcoding a version number

Comment: You want to do it because browsers cache images. If the version or attribute changes, the browser will update the image. This is quite handy if you have uploaded a new version with the same filename.